# V-model equation on value input ( Vue 3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I use vue3 and I have a problem with an input,

I want to display the result of an equation on the value like this:
<InputNumber

```
        id="integeronly"

        :value="element.qu * element.price"

      />

</td>
```

but the problem is that when I put a number in the input quantity the result does not update in a dynamic way I have to click somewhere

I tried V-model instead of :value but it doesn’t work

please can you help me if it’s not possible with :value how to do it with v-model with a function? if so, please tell me how to write the function

Comment: Please provide some details on what you already tried

Comment: it works but it is not dynamic it does not display on the input instantaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      elements: [{id: 1, ref: 'laptop', qu: 5, price: 15}, {id: 2, ref: 'mob', qu: 3, price: 10}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    total(el) {
      return el.qu * el.price
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <table>
  <tr v-for="(element, index) in elements" :key="element.id">
    <td>
      <input id="integeronly" v-model="element.qu" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="integeronly" v-model="element.price" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="integeronly" :value="total(element)" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much I tried again but it doesn't work in the end the problem is the InputNumber of the Primevue framework I will try to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

enter code here
here is the code:

```
<tr v-for="(element, index) in elements" :key="element.id">
     <td>
              <InputNumber id="integeronly" v-model="element.qu" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <InputNumber id="integeronly" v-model="element.price" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <InputNumber id="integeronly" :value="elment.price* element.qu" />
            </td>
          </tr>
```

```js
<script>
data: () => {
    return {
      elements: [
        {
          id: 0,
          ref: "laptop",
          price: "400",
          qu: "2",
        },
      ],
</script>
```

it works but it is not dynamic it does not display on the input instantaneously

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).